# Using Filesystemwatcher to automatically open latest created files with loop

Tags: pdf, filesystemwatcher

I am looking for a script and a method to have Filesystemwatcher automatically open PDF files that had just been created.

Is there a solution? Thanks.
EDIT:
Here is the code/script I am running on.

```
    using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FileSystemWatcherTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\expo";
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

            watcher.Path = path;//assigning path to be watched
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;//make sure watcher will raise event in case of change in folder.
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;//make sure watcher will look into subfolders as well.
            watcher.Filter = "*.*"; //watcher should monitor all types of file.

            watcher.Created += watcher_Created; //register event to be called when a file is created in specified path
            watcher.Changed += watcher_Changed;//register event to be called when a file is updated in specified path
            watcher.Deleted += watcher_Deleted;//register event to be called when a file is deleted in specified path

            while (true) ;//run infinite loop so program doesn't terminate untill we force it.
        }

        static void watcher_Deleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File : " + e.FullPath + " is deleted.");
        }

        static void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File : " + e.FullPath + " is updated.");
        }

        static void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File : " + e.FullPath + " is created.");
        }
    }
}
```

I merely want it to automatically open every new PDF file created in a directory/folder.

Thanks

Comment: Nathan, Could post some code as well as input data and expected output. In this case it would be much easier to get a feedback from the community.

Comment: Are you talking about the .Net class `FileSystemWatcher`? You really should edit your question and add more info especially on the use programming language you (want to) use.

Comment: Yes, filesystemwatcher and I edited/updated it. Thank you